# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token - Cloud Code Parse save function

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Situation - looping over array of events and assigning properties from JSON parsed

Expected outcome - upload to Parse cloud storage

APIs that I'm using -

https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/formats/event/#ebapi-std:format-event
https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide

I'm new to Javascript (there actually might be more than one syntax error)

I don't know why I get this [error](http://imgur.com/wthx2nF) on line 83 when trying to deploy to Parse Cloud Code

What I'm passing in -

```
var cities = ["San Francisco", "London"];
eventsArray = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text)["events"];

loopEvents(eventsArray);
```

---

the whole function as screenshot (syntax highlighting for readability) --> [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWM1r.jpg)

the function as text -->

```
function loopEvents(events) {
   if  (j == cities.length) {j=0};

   for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

      //Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); is not needed ATM I think
      console.log("assigning properties for " + cities[j] + ".");

      list.save({ // saving properties
         number: String(i); //               ****THIS IS THE LINE 83****
         uri: events[i]["resource_uri"];
         url: events[i]["url"];
         id: events[i]["id"];
         name: events[i]["name"]["text"];
         description: events[i]["description"]["text"] || "None provided.";
         status: events[i]["status"];
         capacity: String(events[i]["capacity"]);
         logo: events[i]["logo_id"]["logo"] || "http://www.ecolabelindex.com/files/ecolabel-logos-sized/no-logo-provided.png";
         start: moment(events[i]["start"]["utc"]);
         end: moment(events[i]["end"]["utc"]);
         online: events[i]["online_event"];
         currency: events[i]["currency"];
         ticketClasses: events[i]["ticket_classes"] || "It's freeee!";
         ticketClassesNames: events[i]["ticket_classes"]["name"] || "None provided.";
         ticketClassesCost: events[i]["ticket_classes"]["cost"] || "It's freeee!";
         ticketClassesDescription: events[i]["ticket_classes"]["description"] || "None provided.";
      }, {
         success: function(list) {
            console.log("RIP CloudCode, we had good times!");
         },
         error: function(list, error) {
            console.log("u fuc*ed up, with error: " + error.text + ", son.");
         }
      });
   }
   j++;
}
```

maybe it's all wrong, appreciate the effort and constructive answers ;))) if you need any other info just comment bellow and I'll edit.

#### EDIT.1 - after replacing ; for , I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRs3s.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ticket classes is actually an array and to access it I had to add a expand parameter to the httpRequest, other than that the code itself was fine, thx Tushar for the syntax correction.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using `object`, semi-colon `;` is not valid syntax.

Remove `;` from all the lines inside the object.

```
number: String(i);
//               ^
```

Use `,` comma instead.

```
number: String(i),
//               ^
```

**Code**

```
// Notice the comma at the end of each element

list.save({ // saving properties
    number: String(i),
    uri: events[i]["resource_uri"],
    url: events[i]["url"],
    id: events[i]["id"],
    name: events[i]["name"]["text"],
    description: events[i]["description"]["text"] || "None provided.",
    status: events[i]["status"],
    capacity: String(events[i]["capacity"]),
    logo: events[i]["logo_id"]["logo"] || "http://www.ecolabelindex.com/files/ecolabel-logos-sized/no-logo-provided.png",
    start: moment(events[i]["start"]["utc"]),
    end: moment(events[i]["end"]["utc"]),
    online: events[i]["online_event"],
    currency: events[i]["currency"],
    ticketClasses: events[i]["ticket_classes"] || "It's freeee!",
    ticketClassesNames: events[i]["ticket_classes"]["name"] || "None provided.",
    ticketClassesCost: events[i]["ticket_classes"]["cost"] || "It's freeee!",
    ticketClassesDescription: events[i]["ticket_classes"]["description"] || "None provided."
}, {
```

See [Object creation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects)

Comment: @Ferologics How do you expect us to solve the `error`, without seeing your code

Comment: it's the same but without the semicolon. @Tushar